# ArgumentNullException when accessing a FormView instance

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, argumentnullexception

Background:

I have an ASP.NET page which has a numebr of user controls within it. There are 2 user controls which are of interest. I need to display either one of them or neither of them, depending on the record selected previously.

In the user controls I need to set properties of some controls which are in a FormView. So in my user control code-behind I have a number of properties which look something like this:

```
Private ReadOnly Property phSectionReports() As PlaceHolder
    Get
        Return fvConfirmationReport.FindControl("phSectionReports")
    End Get
End Property
```

The problem:

I am having problems with this Property. Sometimes it is returning Nothing/Null and sometimes it is throwing a NullArgumentException with the message "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: container". The exception is coming from trying to reference the fvConfirmationReport variable. fvConfirmationReport is the ID of my FormView in the page itself.

So I am really after **things to look for** and if any ideas **what sort of conditions (e.g stage in page cycle, etc.) might lead to this?**

An example stack trace is included below.
ASP.NET 3.5 SP1, VB.NET

Thanks,

StackTrace:

```
   at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
   ...snip...
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView.EnsureDataBound()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id)
   at App_UserControls_xxx_ucConfirmationForm.get_phSectionReports() in ucConfirmationForm.ascx.vb:line 343
   at App_UserControls_xxx_ucConfirmationForm.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ucConfirmationForm.ascx.vb:line 412
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   ...snip...
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is...

The problem was coming from a `GridView` within my `FormView`. **One of the items being bound in the `GridView` was Nothing/Null** (a change in the BLL, doh!) causing the `GridView` to crack the sads.

Because accessing the `FormView` in my code-behind was the last bit of unmanaged code before the exception, this is where Visual Studio was displaying the exception. Because of that, every time I had looked at the stack trace I hadn't clicked that it was a `GridView` causing problems at the top. I had `FormView` stuck in my head and that's what I was reading.